# AVAudioPlayer not playing when outsourced in class

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, class, avaudioplayer

I'm relatively new to iOS development, but not new to (object-orientated) programming in general.

I am programming a kind of recorder app, and I need your help when it comes to this:
I've tried to outsource the AVAudioPlayer object into an extra class, `AudioPlayer`, so I can access it from different controllers. 
I does everything it should, except playing any sound. 
Heres a simplified project of my problem:

`ViewController.m`:

```
- (IBAction)playButtonPressed:(id)sender 
{
    NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],@"AudioMemo.m4a",nil];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

    AudioPlayer *myPlayer = [[AudioPlayer alloc] init];
    [myPlayer myPlayAudio:fileURL];
}
```

The rest of the file is empty/standard.

`ViewController.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AudioPlayer.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;

- (IBAction)playButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

`AudioPlayer.m`:

```
#import "AudioPlayer.h"

@implementation AudioPlayer

@synthesize aPlayer;

-(id) myPlayAudio:(NSURL *)myURL 
{
    NSLog(@"in myPlayAudio; before play");

    NSError *err = nil;

    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:NULL];
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
    if(err)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",err);
    }
    aPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL error:&err];
    if(err)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",err);
    }
    [aPlayer play];

    NSLog(@"in myPlayAudio; after play");

    //[audioSession setActive:NO error:&err];

    return err;
}

@end
```

`AudioPlayer.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface AudioPlayer : NSObject <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {
    AVAudioPlayer *aPlayer;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *aPlayer;

-(id) myPlayAudio:(NSURL *) myURL;

@end
```

I've added `AudioToolbox Framework`, activated iTunes file sharing in the .plist file and loaded an `AudioMemo.m4a` file to the documents folder.

It shows the two NSLogs (before + afterplay), but doesn't make any noise. I know I didn't enable the loudspeaker of the iPhone, i wanted to keep it simple in this case. 
Of course I checked volume, silent mode etc.

When I make everything local (put everything in the `ViewController.m`), like most of the tutorials on the net, it works fine.

I searched, but didn't find this problem before, so I would be very thankful if anybody could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see you are using ARC, so this object:

```
AudioPlayer *myPlayer = [[AudioPlayer alloc] init];
```

is released shortly after you allocated it. Keep it in a property instead of a local variable and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, its working. I understand why it is kept when I declare it as a property, but can you tell me why it is released so shortly after allocating it (they way I did it before)?

Comment: I would recommend to read the Apple references about the memory management:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html